# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 47

Tags: php, mysql

My error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'post,view FROM nbb_groups WHERE group_id = '1'' at line 1

```
    $setting_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nbb_settings");
    $setting = mysql_fetch_array($setting_query);
    if( isset( $id ) ) $group_id = userinfo($id,"group_id");
    else $group_id = "4";
    $groupinfo_query = mysql_query("SELECT acp,mod,post,view FROM nbb_groups WHERE             

    group_id = '$group_id'")or die (mysql_error());
    $groupinfo_row = mysql_fetch_array($groupinfo_query);

    $acpstatus = $groupinfo_row["acp"];
    $modstatus = $groupinfo_row["mod"];
    $poststatus = $groupinfo_row["post"];
    $viewstatus = $groupinfo_row["view"];
```

Comment: Write Error's to check it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$groupinfo_query = mysql_query("SELECT `acp`,`mod`,`post`,`view` FROM nbb_groups WHERE       
    group_id = '$group_id'")or die (mysql_error());
```

Enclose the field names with ` (backtick)

field name MOD is reserved word in MYSQL...

Answer (score 0):

`mod` is mysql keyword.

```
MOD(N,M), N % M, N MOD M;
```

change the name of the field.

Refer: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-mod-function.php

Answer (score 0):

Sample Mysql Query :

```
<?php 
$t=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")//Coonector
or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db("category")//Set DB name
or die(mysql_error()); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `nbb_settings` ORDER BY `id` DESC")
or die(mysql_error());
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
echo   $rec['name']."<br>";             
}
mysql_close($t);//Close Session
?>
```

Please Give me errors....